# Configuración de listener de Oracle ip pública

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, servidor, listener

Desde ya aclaro que soy bastante principiante en esto así que cualquier sugerencia y corrección es bienvenida!
Levanté una base de datos Oracle (21c) en un servidor casero, básicamente una máquina que formateé, instalé Centos 7 y pude configurar todo, incluído el listener, para que se puedan conectar de manera local (misma red wifi).
Ahora tenía ganas de replicar eso pero en un servidor que tenemos comprado, que tiene windows server, pero con una IP pública, para que se pueda acceder a la base de datos de manera global. Supuse que los pasos eran parecidos pero se ve que no, el listener me "levanta" (no genera errores) pero me sale como status "unknown" en vez de ready. Y cuando intento conectarme claramente no me deja. Ya declaré las variables de entorno, ya permití acceso al puerto desde el firewall, ya reinicié la base de datos y el listener. Les paso los archivos como los tengo configurados:
listener.ora:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\user\homes\OraDB21Home1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle21c)
      (SID_NAME = irm2)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Oracle21c\bin\oraclr.dll")
      (SID_NAME = irm2)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle21c)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = *nombre_de_pc*)(PORT = 1522))
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\user

SAVE_CONFIG_ON_STOP_LISTENER = TRUE
```

tnsnames.ora:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\user\homes\OraDB21Home1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

IRM2 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = *ip_publica_pc*)(PORT = 1522))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = irm2)
    )
  )

IRM2PDB1 =
  (ADDRESS =
    (PROTOCOL = TCP)
    (HOST = *ip_publica_pc*)
    (PORT = 1522)
  )
```

irm2 es el nombre de la base y del sid, irm2pdb1 es el nombre del contenedor pero eso lo agregué por un video así que puede estar de más. Obvio que donde dice *ip_publica_pc* *nombre_pc* están los valores correctos. Alguna sugerencia de cuál puede ser el problema? Muchas gracias! Cualquier cosa que me ayude a investigar me sirve, dado que ya no sé qué probar.